# c++ strings line reversion to the console

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, console

I just want to know what is wrong with this C++ code:
I have to get chars from the console and count how many lines were written. Then i have to show them in reverse order. I.e: if i write 3 lines: "hi", "im", "lucas" with a '\n' ending each one. I have to reverse them, so it writes "lucas", "im", "hi", line by line.
First tought: i "save" the lines in a vector of "strings" then i show them up with an iterator going from the end to the beggining.
Im using VSCode with g++ and it seems there is a problem with the final iterator vector loop. The program stops there and throws a SIGINT interrupt.
Why does this happen? How to correct it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    string strLines = "";
    int c;
    do {
        c = getc(stdin);
        strLines += c;
    } while (c != EOF);
    size_t oldIndex = 0;
    size_t newIndex;
    int totalStrings = 0;
    vector<string> strVector;
    while (1)
    {
        newIndex = strLines.find('\n', oldIndex);
        if (newIndex == string::npos)
            break;
        string strToPush = strLines.substr(oldIndex, newIndex+1);
        strVector.push_back(strToPush + '\0');
        oldIndex = newIndex+1;
        totalStrings++;
    } 
    //reverse string
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = strVector.end()-1 ; it != strVector.begin(); it--)
    {
        string strShow = *it;
        cout << *it;
    }
    c = getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Comment: A stack would be better.

Comment: You're not even iterating backwards. Why is there a totalStrings variable? You never use it, and vectors know how big they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with what you've shown. Unnecessary variables, no actual backwards iteration, bad loop conditions, etc.

Here's code with a vector:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::vector<std::string> entries;

  do {
    std::cout << "Enter a thing: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    if (!line.empty()) {
      entries.push_back(line);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  } while (!line.empty());

  for (auto it = entries.rbegin(); it != entries.rend(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

If you want to go backwards, you use a reverse iterator. It's as easy as that. But a vector is not the ideal data structure for this. Stacks are perfectly suited.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::stack<std::string> entries;

  do {
    std::cout << "Enter a thing: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    if (!line.empty()) {
      entries.push(line);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  } while (!line.empty());

  while (!entries.empty()) {
    std::cout << entries.top() << ' ';
    entries.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Both pieces of code give you what you want, in a much more straightforward matter. They terminate the user-entry loop when you just press enter without typing anything else (empty string). When taking advantage of the Standard Library (vectors, stacks, strings, etc.), do take the time to familiarize yourself with what they are able to do. Common tasks are likely taken care of for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. No need for null terminator is `std::string`
2. You never add the last string to your vector, if you encounter an endline character (`\n`) you break, and don't add the last string to the vector. You can solve it by adding right after the loop `strVector.push_back(strLines.substr(oldIndex))`
3. As @sweenish mentioned in the comments, a `stack` would be better
4. You make a lot of copies. Either use `std::move` or in-place copies.
5. You miss the first element anyways, use `rbegin()` and `rend()`
6. (Found it when running) you should use `substr(oldIndex, newIndex-oldIndex)`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    string strLines = "this\nis\nan\nexample\nfor\nsplitting";
    size_t oldIndex = 0;
    size_t newIndex;
    vector<string> strVector;
    while (1)
    {
        newIndex = strLines.find('\n', oldIndex);
        if (newIndex == string::npos) {
            break;
        }
        strVector.push_back(strLines.substr(oldIndex, newIndex-oldIndex));
        oldIndex = newIndex+1;
    } 
    strVector.push_back(strLines.substr(oldIndex));
    //reverse string
    for (auto it = strVector.rbegin() ; it != strVector.rend(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this what you are showing me is the right way to do it. And as you say i'ts much better a stack than a vector. Thanks very much